# Codemirror - minimum lines number

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

Anbody does have an solution for a min lines number - in [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net)?

min-height worked for me but do not insert empty lines for the height.

**JS**

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    gutter: true,
    lineWrapping: true
});
```

**CSS**

```
.CodeMirror-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto; overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  min-height: 300px; /* the minimum height */
}
```

Maybe there is a simple solution to insert empty lines for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the `min-height: 300px;` and initialize the editor with new lines as the starting value:

```js
var minLines = 3;
var startingValue = '';
for (var i = 0; i < minLines; i++) {
    startingValue += '\n';
}

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    gutter: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    value: startingValue
});
```

currently, CodeMirror's `value` option does not seem to have an affect for up to version 2.21. this can be easily bypassed by using `setValue()` after initialization:

```js
///...
// initialize as before, omitting the value option

editor.setValue(startingValue);
```

**note:**
make sure not to set `autoClearEmptyLines: true` as it will clash and cancel out the inserted empty lines.

Comment: check the JS console. you are not including the CodeMirror scripts in the document.

Comment: of couse I did, look at the tab on the left side: "Manage Resources"

Comment: the link for minus is broken. fix this, reset styles to the default (remove `min-height` etc.) and investigate further.

Comment: this solution now works for me, but already there is the problem after deleting, via CMD+A and Backspace, the _empty lines_ the editor resets.

Comment: If I understood @mrzmyr  correctly, I too think that's a problem. Besides, as you are typing your code, when you insert new-lines, those blank lines are pushed to the bottom. It doesn't look good.
In any case, apparently there's no easy/standard solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

so guys I got the solution.
on any reason the editor does not get the `value` from the configuration options so i set the value after it. @Eliran thanks, i used your method to set the value.

```
editor.setValue(startingValue);
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/vujLv/1/

Comment: Thx man, it worked! @Eliran was right on so many things so I fixed your jsFiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/vujLv/18/

Comment: Thanks, I'm loading via jQuery and for some reason had to use this method.  Even though it's part of the accepted answer, I just flat out missed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.setValue( value + "\n".repeat(10) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am defining a CodeMirror option "minLines" and manipulating some keybindings and history.

This disables the CodeMirror instance's lines from ever going below the minLines value, not just setting so many lines on init.

You can just pop this in a file named "minLines.js" and put that in */addons* and it's ready to use.

Here is my [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/ExYygxN).

```
// set minimum number of lines CodeMirror instance is allowed to have
(function (mod) {
    mod(CodeMirror);
})(function (CodeMirror) {
    var fill = function (cm, start, n) {
        while (start < n) {
            let count = cm.lineCount();
            cm.replaceRange("\n", { line: count - 1 }), start++;
            // remove new line change from history (otherwise user could ctrl+z to remove line)
            let history = cm.getHistory();
            history.done.pop(), history.done.pop();
            cm.setHistory(history);
            if (start == n) break;
        }
    };
    var pushLines = function (cm, selection, n) {
        // push lines to last change so that "undo" doesn't add lines back
        var line = cm.lineCount() - 1;
        var history = cm.getHistory();
        history.done[history.done.length - 2].changes.push({
            from: {
                line: line - n,
                ch: cm.getLine(line - n).length,
                sticky: null
            },
            text: [""],
            to: { line: line, ch: 0, sticky: null }
        });
        cm.setHistory(history);
        cm.setCursor({ line: selection.start.line, ch: selection.start.ch });
    };

    var keyMap = {
        Backspace: function (cm) {
            var cursor = cm.getCursor();
            var selection = {
                start: cm.getCursor(true),
                end: cm.getCursor(false)
            };

            // selection
            if (selection.start.line !== selection.end.line) {
                let func = function (e) {
                    var count = cm.lineCount(); // current number of lines
                    var n = cm.options.minLines - count; // lines needed
                    if (e.key == "Backspace" || e.code == "Backspace" || e.which == 8) {
                        fill(cm, 0, n);
                        if (count <= cm.options.minLines) pushLines(cm, selection, n);
                    }
                    cm.display.wrapper.removeEventListener("keydown", func);
                };
                cm.display.wrapper.addEventListener("keydown", func); // fires after CodeMirror.Pass

                return CodeMirror.Pass;
            } else if (selection.start.ch !== selection.end.ch) return CodeMirror.Pass;

            // cursor
            var line = cm.getLine(cursor.line);
            var prev = cm.getLine(cursor.line - 1);
            if (
                cm.lineCount() == cm.options.minLines &&
                prev !== undefined &&
                cursor.ch == 0
            ) {
                if (line.length) {
                    // add a line because this line will be attached to previous line per default behaviour
                    cm.replaceRange("\n", { line: cm.lineCount() - 1 });
                    return CodeMirror.Pass;
                } else cm.setCursor(cursor.line - 1, prev.length); // set cursor at end of previous line
            }
            if (cm.lineCount() > cm.options.minLines || cursor.ch > 0)
                return CodeMirror.Pass;
        },
        Delete: function (cm) {
            var cursor = cm.getCursor();
            var selection = {
                start: cm.getCursor(true),
                end: cm.getCursor(false)
            };

            // selection
            if (selection.start.line !== selection.end.line) {
                let func = function (e) {
                    var count = cm.lineCount(); // current number of lines
                    var n = cm.options.minLines - count; // lines needed
                    if (e.key == "Delete" || e.code == "Delete" || e.which == 46) {
                        fill(cm, 0, n);
                        if (count <= cm.options.minLines) pushLines(cm, selection, n);
                    }
                    cm.display.wrapper.removeEventListener("keydown", func);
                };
                cm.display.wrapper.addEventListener("keydown", func); // fires after CodeMirror.Pass

                return CodeMirror.Pass;
            } else if (selection.start.ch !== selection.end.ch) return CodeMirror.Pass;

            // cursor
            var line = cm.getLine(cursor.line);
            if (cm.lineCount() == cm.options.minLines) {
                if (
                    cursor.ch == 0 &&
                    (line.length !== 0 || cursor.line == cm.lineCount() - 1)
                )
                    return CodeMirror.Pass;
                if (cursor.ch == line.length && cursor.line + 1 < cm.lineCount()) {
                    // add a line because next line will be attached to this line per default behaviour
                    cm.replaceRange("\n", { line: cm.lineCount() - 1 });
                    return CodeMirror.Pass;
                } else if (cursor.ch > 0) return CodeMirror.Pass;
            } else return CodeMirror.Pass;
        }
    };

    var onCut = function (cm) {
        var selection = {
            start: cm.getCursor(true),
            end: cm.getCursor(false)
        };
        setTimeout(function () {
            // wait until after cut is complete
            var count = cm.lineCount(); // current number of lines
            var n = cm.options.minLines - count; // lines needed
            fill(fm, 0, n);
            if (count <= cm.options.minLines) pushLines(cm, selection, n);
        });
    };

    var start = function (cm) {
        // set minimum number of lines on init
        var count = cm.lineCount(); // current number of lines
        cm.setCursor(count); // set the cursor at the end of existing content
        fill(cm, 0, cm.options.minLines - count);

        cm.addKeyMap(keyMap);

        // bind events
        cm.display.wrapper.addEventListener("cut", onCut, true);
    };
    var end = function (cm) {
        cm.removeKeyMap(keyMap);

        // unbind events
        cm.display.wrapper.removeEventListener("cut", onCut, true);
    };

    CodeMirror.defineOption("minLines", undefined, function (cm, val, old) {
        if (val !== undefined && val > 0) start(cm);
        else end(cm);
    });
});
```