# CodeMirror missing line numbers, it shows a simple textarea only

Tags: numbers, line, mirror

I have integrated **CodeMirror** with below code,

```
<style>
.CodeMirror {
    border-top: 1px solid #888; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
</style>
<body>
    <textarea id="myCode"></textarea>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        var myTextarea = $("#myCode")[0];
        editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
          lineNumbers: true
        });
      };
    </script>
</body>
```

It shows a normal textarea only, which doesn't look like an editor and the line numbers are missing. Please help me if anything I am missing.

When I replace the line `var myTextarea = $("#myCode");` with `var myTextarea = $("#myCode")[0]`, it displays the edotor as well.

Answer (score 6):

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vujLv/18/).

HTML:

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var minLines = 5;
var startingValue = '';
for (var i = 1; i < minLines; i++) {
    startingValue += '\n';
}

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    gutter: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    value: startingValue
});

//FIX FOR MIN LINES
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380759/codemirror-minimum-lines-number
editor.setValue(startingValue);
```