# I have a problem with the codemirror editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

[image]

as you can see in the image, I have an error.
when I also write something in html, it puts the text in the center
then the text goes under the number line, and creates a mess

I checked if there is a css that conflicts by canceling other css styles of the page, but the same happens

this is the code I entered

```
 var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("message"), {
    lineNumbers: true,

    mode:  "javascript",
    mode: "htmlmixed",
    theme: "shadowfox",
    mode: "css",

  extraKeys: {"Alt-F": "findPersistent"}
  });
```

how do i solve?

Comment: Please share your css.

Comment: @Christian [https://www.natnox.com/newthradstile.css

Comment: @Christian  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.18.1/styles/default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,100,400,300,600,700,800"/>
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: I tried to delete all the css but it remains the same

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you still have a `text-align: center;` somewhere, like

```
textarea {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I am not sure how you include line numbers, but [this fiddle shows line numbers and how centered text can happen](http://jsfiddle.net/8o7p94kf/). The example in the fiddle above comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335314/3842598).

Comment: How? Any details for us?

Comment: there is a text-align: center on the body, and then thanks to your code I solved the problem of the lines, thank you very much